# Getting an error : Reverse for 'college' not found. 'college' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('college/', views.CollegeView.as_view(), name="college"),
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms
from accounts.models import College
# Create your views here.

class CollegeView(CreateView):
    form_class = College
    fields = ['college']
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/college.html"

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("college")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "Display name"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"

class CollegeForm(forms.Form):
    fields = ("college")
```

If i try to redirect the success url to login or logout then it works but for college it is not working

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using namespaces for urls.

Try to set `success_url` according to *`app_name`* like this:

```py
success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:college")
```

Or remove namespace from the root urls.py file in *include* method